# Cross-Thread Call using MVP WIndows Forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, mvp

I would like to use MVP Design pattern for a WinForm App but i'm facing the problem of calling a View Update from another thread.

Here's my code

**MODEL**

```
public class Model : IModel
{
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public async void LongOperation(IHomeView View)
    {          

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            View.StatusListView = i.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**PRESENTER**

```
public class HomePresenter
{
    IHomeView _IView;
    IModel _IModel;

    Model _Model = new Model();

    public HomePresenter(IHomeView IView)
    {
        _IView = IView;                                 
    }        

    public async void LaunchLongOperation()
    {           
        await Task.Run(() => _Model.LongOperation(_IView));            
    }


}
```

**INTERFACE VIEW-PRESENTER**

```
public interface IHomeView
{
    string StatusListView { get; set; }
}
```

**INTERFACE PRESENTER-MODEL**

```
public interface IModel
{
    string Status { get; set; }
}
```

**FORM:**

```
public partial class frmMain : Form, IHomeView
{
    HomePresenter _Presenter;

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _Presenter = new HomePresenter(this);      
    }



    public string StatusListView
    {
        get
        {
            return lstActivityLog.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            lstActivityLog.Items.Add(value);
        }
    }

    private void btnAvvia_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _Presenter.launchLongOperation();
    }        
}
```

i would like to update a list view in the Main form during the long operations of the Model class.

Which is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code without debugging, you'll be surprised about it works!

The quick and dirty way to make it work in debugging mode as well is to add   `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` into the constructor of your form.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IHomeView
    {
        HomePresenter _Presenter;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;   //<-- add this
            _Presenter = new HomePresenter(this);
        }

        public string StatusListView
        {
            get
            {
                return lstActivityLog.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                 lstActivityLog.Items.Add(value);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _Presenter.LaunchLongOperation();
        }
    }
```